# What does an arrow reference to a not yet defined key do in perl?

Tags: perl, reference

The arrow notation is asked about a lot here, but I can't seem to find the specific example I have. I would like to apologise in advance if I just missed it.

I have been given an assignment to correct some Perl code, but I simply do not understand what this line of code is supposed to do:

```
my $aref = [1,2,3,4];

my $x = $aref->{structure};
```

So as this is part of the assignment, the line itself could be the mistake, and there is more to the code too but my question is why is there an undefined keyword `{structure}`? What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried running that code? What error message do you get? Do you understand it?

I agree that it's hard to know what sort of "fix" is expected, but I don't want to introduce you to something that you're not supposed to have covered yet. I think it's fair to say that deleting the second line is the most appropriate fix, but I doubt if that's what your tutor expects!

Do you know that `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` creates an *anonymous array* and returns a *reference* to it? If not then that is something you can google

So `my $aref = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` puts into `$aref` a reference to an array (with four elements). Do you know how to access array elements from references? If not then [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) (a tutorial) and [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) are essential

And do you know how to access ordinary arrays, and ordinary hashes? I'm concerned that you think `structure` is a "keyword". Maybe you need to read [*Perl variable types* in `perldoc perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types)

I hope that helps. If I get a better sense of where you're stuck I can give you much more appropriate help

Comment: Thanks! And yes I am aware about anonymous arrays and referencing, I am starting to think one of the mistakes in the code is that it should read as: 
my $x = $aref=>{structure};
Also I have no idea how to do inline code blocks, so sorry about that.
If that line of code is correct what would is do now? And how would I access the list items?
Hope that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @Michael Ad: _And how would I access the list items?_ - explained in the above docs. You really need read the `perlreftut` to understand the difference between `$r->[2]` and `$r->{2}`.

Comment: @Michael: No. `my $x = $aref=>{structure}` is wrong. The `=>` operator is known at the *fat comma*, and is nothing to do with the dereferencing arrow `->`. It does exactly the same as a comma except that if there is a "bareword" (an alphanumeric string, basically) before it then it implicitly quotes it, so `( xx => 1)` is identical to `( 'xx', 1 )`. Because `$aref` isn't a bareword (it has a dollar sign in it), `my $x = $aref=>{structure}` is the same as `my $x = $aref, {structure}`.

Comment: Have you tried running those two lines of code? Do you understand the error message?